# How to change the names of the column/row of the matrix in R?

Tags: r

```
    adj_estimate <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
min_column
[1] "V1"
```

I want the name of the first row and first column of the matrix to be V1. min_column is from my previous lines of codes. Basically this is an iterative process. I will update the name of column and rows after each step.

I try

```
colnames(adj_estimate)[1] <- min_column
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: `colnames(adj_estimate)` returns `NULL`. You cannot name just the first column. This works: `colnames(adj_estimate) <- c("min_column", paste0("non_min_colum", 1L:4L)).` The same holds for the row names: `rownames(adj_estimate) <- paste0("V", 1L:5L)` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no column or row names for the matrix as they are all `NULL`.

```
> adj_estimate <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
> colnames(adj_estimate)
NULL
```

You can pass an initial set of names using `dimnames`.

`adj_estimate <- matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, dimnames = list(1:5, 1:5))`

From there, you can modify the names.

`colnames(adj_estimate)[1] <- 'V1.min_column'`